# Geo-referencing large PDF files when DXF doesn't work

Tags: qgis, georeferencing, pdf, dxf

I've a 4567kb PDF which won't load even into the georeferencer (stops responding) but a 1538kb one from the same source with the same encoding will. Why? If I drag it it then it loads but won't let me see it without crashing.

I have it in a DXF as well and if I drag it in or import as a vector layer  then 'not valid or a supported data source' if dxf2shp then mini dump, if using the updated DXF import/convert plugin then I get 'Plugin Fehler: process 'gdalogr:convertformat' could not start please restart QGIS'.

Why are none of these working/any solutions? Can see the files in DWGSee/Acrobat so it can't be the files, but using a fairly slow computer so is it just inadequate processing capacity?

Using 2.18.3 but have tried 2.16.3 and 2.6.1 as I still have them on the computer.

Comment: 1) basically DXF is better than PDF 2) since 2.18.2 is a new built-in dwg / dxf importer 3) I think the DXF is corrupt. You should upload this DXF for testing

Comment: I've not been able to get any to work since the latest upgrade, all from different places and all open fine on DWGSee. Unfortunately I cant upload as they are 'sensitive' and I wouldn't know how sorry.